# Disabling Textarea from CSS

Tags: html, css, input, textarea

In order to disable a textarea (or any other input element), you can:

- In HTML, you can write:
  `<textarea id='mytextarea' disabled></textarea>`
- From jQuery, you can:
  `$("#mytextarea").attr("disabled","disabled");`
- CSS? Is it possible to disable the textarea with CSS?

Comment: Even if you can, semantically CSS is for display, not behavior so I would say css is not the proper way to disable stuff (you can hide it using `display:none` if you want)

Comment: @Mark Why ? disabled is an attribute of a textarea, the line above in bArmageddon is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure that disabling a textarea can be automatically considered behavior, it is more style and UI that disables the user from inserting an input. What functionality does `disabled` has other than preventing and input change? That could be considered a UI issue these days...

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` should stop the text area being clicked on in Firefox 3.6+, Safari 3+ and Chrome 5+. You can then apply all the colour effects. You might look at putting javascript into css files if your curios, I think this may be possible with IE's dynamic properties. But all of these are hackish! :)

Comment: @Annan: You can still tab to it, though.

Comment: @BoltClock True. I don't know any way to get around that.

Comment: @AnnanFay your idea helped a lot with some dirty prototyping – thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can make a textarea appear disabled, but you can't actually disable it.

Using JavaScript, all you're really doing is modifying the same DOM attribute that's set by the HTML `disabled` attribute, so using HTML and JavaScript you're *essentially* doing the same thing. CSS, however, is completely out of this picture, as it doesn't do DOM manipulation of any sort — all it controls is the appearance (visual or otherwise) of an element, not its behavior.

Answer (score 10):

In a Project I have a container with a textarea and some buttons inside.
To disable the whole thing I append a class to it with the following code:

```
.disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.disabled:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute; 
}

<div class="disabled">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <!-- textarea, buttons and other input elements -->
</div>
```

While the opacity is only for the show, the :after element is doing the work. All elements in the container are no longer reacting to click and mouseover (reaching them with the tabulator will still work though). For my needs and in my case this works fine and is an easy css hack.

Comment: Excellent idea. Favorited. However you need to set moz-use-focus to ignore of the fields otherwise users can tab into it.

Answer (score 9):

CSS deals with styles.  Disabling an element is functional.

Of course, CSS is becoming more functional with things like transitions and that's more of a grey area.   But the purpose of CSS is to keep it as styles and not to control element functional control.

No, css cannot disable elements.

You can "fake" a disabled control styling it to visually look disabled.

Answer (score 6):

```
 <textarea placeholder="This is a textarea, and it is not clickable" style="pointer-events: none"></textarea>
```

You can make elements completely unclickable with css: `point-events: none;`

```css
textarea {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="This is a textarea, and it is not clickable"></textarea>
```

Comment: you can still use tab to select

Comment: To disable selecting using tab: Add attribute ``tabindex="-1"`` (e.g. using JS). Unfortunately not CSS...

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be done in CSS. But, you can style the input as "disabled" in CSS and use the property maxlength="0" in the HTML code so people won't be able to write in it. Also, be sure to change the pointer style as the right one so people won't see the pointer that tell them to write in the box.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in pure CSS unfortunately... you'd have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack.

```
<textArea class="tailLog">This page is waiting for something.</textArea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(  function(){
            $(".tailLog").off().on("keydown", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            });
     });
</script>
```

The way it works is this. Whenever the user tries to enter anything, we use jquery to catch the event. Then we tell the event we don't want it to do its default behavior. As I say its a hack but its an effective one in a pinch.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#myTextarea{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: That stops the user from focusing the textarea by clicking on it. It doesn't prevent them using other methods (such as the Tab key) to focus it, not does it prevent the textarea being a successful control and submitting any data in it.

Comment: This is also the same as [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066124/19068).

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with above answers "Not possible in pure CSS unfortunately"
But if You can make parent element pointer events none then it will do the job but it can be reversed from inspect elements

```
<div class="disabled">
 <textarea></textarea>
 <!-- textarea, buttons and other input elements -->
</div>

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;;
}
```

Comment: `pointer-events: none` stops the user from focusing the textarea by clicking on it. It doesn't prevent them using other methods (such as the Tab key) to focus it, not does it prevent the textarea being a successful control and submitting any data in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a readonly attribute in the html like

`<textarea readonly>`

the text can no longer be amended

Comment: That HTML attribute is HTML, not CSS (and making something readonly isn't the same as disabling it).

Answer (score -1):

In case you've a textarea disabled this way:

```html
<textarea disabled="disabled">foobar</textarea>
```

You can easily style it with the following CSS:

```css
textarea[disabled="disabled"]
{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how to disable a textarea with CSS, not how to style a textarea that has already been disabled with HTML.